# Bootstrap row selector is not working well

Tags: dc.js, c3.js, bootstrap-grid

This is weird: I added a row selector for each chart, but the last chart C3 chart is always in the top right corner.

I uploaded the charts and the elements code. I cannot find any error. I am using dc.js and c3.js.

I am using mongodb to store the data. retrieve the data using node.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any help!!! Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is happening. Maybe last chart does not have *.dc-chart* - what happens if you add it there?

Comment: More specifically, try styling the div for the c3 chart with `float: left`. That's what dc.js does [(for better or worse)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/673).

Comment: @Gordon you answer is helpful!!!! Thanks!!!!